# Please explain how this is implemented

Tags: c++

What I've seen and been taught about encapsulation is that we can have data members as private and member functions are public.

But C++ Primer defines encapsulation as:

> Separation of implementation from interface; encapsulation hides
>   the implementation details of a type. In C++, encapsulation is enforced by putting the implementation in the private part of a class.

The last line is the confusing part: **putting the implementation in the private part of a class**.  By implementation, he means the function definitions, right? I mean, I've never seen a function declared public (as prototype) and implemented in private.

I'm really confused. Please explain what he's trying to say with a simple example.

Comment: maybe he is talking about the pimpl pattern http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom

Comment: No, by "implementation" he means the class members (data and functions) that aren't part of the public interface, but are used to implement its behaviour. One way of encapsulating them is to make them private.

Answer (score 2):

The concept being explained is more abstract than you're thinking about it. The "interface" is "what callers expect the object to do". And the implementation is technically how the class actually carries out those operations.

So for example, take a `List` class. Code that *uses* a `List` should only care about its interface: things like `addObject()`, `clear()`, `getSize()`, `sort()`.

But the *implementation* of `List` -- which callers should not care about -- may vary drastically on how to accomplish this. For example the data could be stored as a linked list. Or maybe as a dynamic array. This is "private" implementation details that only the `List` class needs to care about. There will indeed probably be a `private:` method called `reallocate()` or so. Callers should never use this; it's an implementation detail -- not part of the public interface. Callers should not care how the `List` allocates its storage.

Similarly, a `sort()` method implies it will sort objects in the list. That's the interface. But the implementation may use any number of algorithms to perform the sort. The implementation is a private detail - and *may* be done in private methods. In any case it's hidden from callers.

```
template<typename T>
class List
{
public:
    // public members are part of the interface: the externally-visible behavior "contract" your object guarantees.
    void addObject(const T& obj)
    {
        // call private methods to help carry out implementation.
        ensureCapacity(this->sizeAllocated + 1);
        this->sizeAdvertized += 1;
        // ... and copy the object into the right position in this->data...
    }

    size_t getSize() const
    {
        return this->sizeAdvertized;
    }

    // ... other members like clear(), sort()...

private:
    T* data;
    size_t sizeAllocated;
    size_t sizeAdvertized;

    // this needs to be private because it's not part of the interface. Callers
    // should never need to call this.
    void ensureCapacity(size_t requestedCapacity)
    {
        if(sizeAllocated >= requestedCapacity)
            return;// already have enough storage available.

        // ... reallocate this->data, copy existing items to the new array...

        this->sizeAllocated = requestedCapacity;
    }
};
```

And finally to address what you said:

> I mean, I've never seen a function declared public (as prototype) and implemented in private.

"Private" again is more abstract than you're thinking. The implementation of a class is basically *always* "private" in that it's hidden from callers. It doesn't necessarily mean the `private:` access specifier. It just means that it's not exposed to callers. Implementation of public methods fits this description.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed have private functions (methods) in a class. Consider:

```
class X 
{
public:
  // public interface - this never changes and you provide documentation for it
  void do_something();

private:
  // this private interface is likely to change. consumers of this class
  // are prevented from calling these methods unless they are friends
  void first_private_thing();
  void second_private_thing();

};

// definition
void X::do_something()
{
  // private implementation in public method
  first_private_thing();
  second_private_thing();
}
```

there are further extensions on this theme, for example:

```
class Base
{
public:
  // public non-virtual interface
  void do_something();

private:
  // calls private virtual implementation
  virtual void do_something_impl() = 0;

};

// definition:
void Base::do_something()
{
  do_something_impl();
}
```

Comment: Thank you brother. I love you. But, is this a good practice? I've gone through some text books and online resources and I've never seen such an implementation.

Comment: Also, what if I declare the `do_something()` method in public, just like you have and instead of defining it outside the class using a binary scope resolution operator, can I define it in the private zone? Will it be a compilation error?

Comment: No that's fine. Although if possible it's better practice to hide implementation in a cpp file if you can. Interfaces describe concepts, implementation details are irrelevant to the person using your class, provided your implementation produces the advertised (documented) outcome. Re text books... Remember that those who can do, those who can't teach ;)

Comment: Oh...just one last thing. So, if we did what I said the the previous comment, what does it mean? On one hand we are declaring the function to be public, but we are defining it in private instead if outside the class. So, does the function still remain public? I think so.

Comment: Public and private only control who can call the function, not whether you can see what it does. The terms public and private don't apply to the code in the function (that is even more private than private because no one can call it). It is perfectly possible to have a private function (others can't call it) that is defined inline (but everyone can read the source code).